# ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH while trying to enable HTTPS on localhost using OpenSSL

Tags: node.js, networking, openssl

I am trying to enable HTTPS on my pure nodeJS server (No express.js). To enable HTTPS I am using Openssl and generating keys and certificates which I can then load into the server file.

###################################

**The problem:**

###################################

[image: Browser Error]

I checked online, and most people were saying that the problem is occurring due to the `common name` of my CA certificate and Server certificate being the same. I did enter different values for both, and still the error persists.

######################################

**Commands used to generate keys and certificates:**

######################################

```
# Generating our private keys

openssl genpkey -algorithm ed25519 -outform pem -out ca_pvt_key.pem
openssl genpkey -algorithm ed25519 -outform pem -out server_pvt_key.pem

# Generating our certificate

openssl req -inform pem -key ca_pvt_key.pem -days 36000 -x509 -config openssl-ca.cnf -nodes -outform pem -out ca_cert.pem
openssl x509 -outform der -in ca_cert.pem -out ca_cert.crt

# Creating SCR (Server Certificate Request)

openssl req -new -config openssl-server.cnf -key server_pvt_key.pem -nodes -outform pem -out server_certificate.csr

# Creating required index.txt and serial.txt files for openssl ca

touch index.txt
echo '01' > serial.txt

# Generating our final signed certificate
openssl ca -config openssl-ca.cnf -notext -policy signing_policy -extensions signing_req -out server_certificate.pem -infiles server_certificate.csr
openssl ca -config openssl-ca.cnf -notext -policy signing_policy -extensions signing_req -out server_certificate.crt -infiles server_certificate.csr

cat server_certificate.pem > cert_chain.pem
cat ca_cert.pem >> cert_chain.pem
```

##################################

**Configuration file snippets for above commands**

##################################

CA config file

```
[ ca_extensions ]

subjectKeyIdentifier   = hash
authorityKeyIdentifier = keyid:always, issuer
basicConstraints       = critical, CA:true
keyUsage               = keyCertSign, cRLSign
```

Server certificate config file

```
####################################################################
[ server_req_extensions ]

subjectKeyIdentifier = hash
basicConstraints     = CA:FALSE
keyUsage             = digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
subjectAltName       = @alternate_names
nsComment            = "OpenSSL Generated Certificate"

####################################################################
[ alternate_names ]

DNS.1  = localhost

# IPv4 localhost
IP.1     = 127.0.0.1

# IPv6 localhost
IP.2     = ::1
```

#################################

**Server File snippet**

#################################

```
const port = 3000;

const options = {
    host: "localhost",
    port: port,
    path: "/",
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
    requestCert: true,
    agent: false,
    key: fs.readFileSync(path.join(path.resolve(__dirname, "../../"), "/certs/server_pvt_key.pem")),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(path.join(path.resolve(__dirname, "../../"), "/certs/cert_chain.pem")),
};

const server = https.createServer(options, (req, res) => {
  // Pure node server
});
```

##################################

**System details**

##################################

I am running a podman container having OpenSUSE Tumbleweed. The host system in Ubuntu 22.04LTS.

##################################

**Extra details**

##################################

I added the ca_cert.crt file to `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates` on Ubuntu. I also added the server_certificate.crt and server_pvt_key.pem into `/etc/ssl/certs and /etc/ssl/private` respectively.

##################################

**Testssl Output**

##################################

[image: Testssl O/P]

##################################

**curl**

##################################

curl does fetch me my site HTML. However, the moment I am in the browser, I get the cipher error.

##################################

**Browser Trust Store**

##################################

I am using Brave Browser. When I try to import my `ca_cert.pem` or `ca_cert.crt` file into the `Authorities` tab in Brave, it shows me the following:

[image: Authority Import Error]

Anyone have any idea why this is happening and how I could fix it?